# Mocking groovy.sql.Sql.call(_,_,_) method

Tags: grails, groovy, mocking, spock

I am trying to mock the groovy.sql.Sql call(query, params[], closure) class.
Below is method, within a DatabaseService class file, that I am attempting this on.

```
public void getUsers(List<User> developerList, Sql sql) {
    sql.call("{? = call GETUSERS()}", [Sql.resultSet(OracleTypes.CURSOR)]) { result ->
        while (result.next()) {
            User user = new User()
            user .email = result.EMAIL
            user .lastName = result.LASTNAME
        }
    }
}
```

My mock does achieve the task, however, I do not want the mocked closure to execute. I want to mock the .call(*,*,_) method to only skip the database logic, and return back a list to the closure in the getUsers() method. I want the closure to execute in getUsers() method, not the mocked up method.

Below is the mockup I have written in SPOCK.

```
void "test getUsers(list,sql) some results"() {
    DataSource mockedSource = Mock(DataSource)
    Sql mockedSql = Mock(Sql)
    DatabaseService databaseService = new DatabaseService()
    databaseService.dataSource = mockedSource
    List<User> userList= new ArrayList<>();

    when:
    databaseService.getUsers(userList, mockedSql)

    then:
    1 * mockedSql.call(_, _, _) >> { return [[EMAIL: "A", LASTNAME: "B"]] }
    userList.size() == 1
}
```

As imagined, this mockup overwrites the original method closure, and my list is never populated.. I certainly do not want to rewrite my class to use Java, nor can I change the stored procedure that is executed.

Comment: Why not just mock the service method to just return the list

Comment: because that will not test if the closure works

Comment: Hmmmm... I'd either fake the datasource, or extract the closure out so it's testable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try :
int resultSetIdx = 0
def resutSet = Mock(ResultSet)
  ...
then:
  1 * mockedSql.call(_, _, _) >> { args -> args[2].call(resultSet) }
  2 * mockedResultset.next() >> { ++resultSetIdx > 1 ? false: true}
  1 * mockedResultset.getString("EMAIL") >> "A"
```

In the getUsers method() change

```
user.lastName = result.LASTNAME
user.email = result.EMAIL
```

To

```
user.lastName = result.getString("LASTNAME")
user.email = result.getString("EMAIL")
```

However, you shouldn't mock `Sql`, but rewrite your service/dao layer to be more testable. test the dao with an inmemory db, and the service layer with a mocked dao.

Comment: the original method throws groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.next() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: get(int), get(int), set(int, java.lang.Object), set(int, java.lang.Object), wait(), head() in the  (result.next()) {} ) invocation within the getUsers method

Comment: While I understand I could re-write it to be more testable, I would infer that mocking methods, but omitting closures should not be that difficult. In addition, I'd rather re-use already built methods, than write it all from scratch. :) Maybe there is an alternative method in groovy, that would return back a result set from a preparedCall, that I am not aware of

Comment: it's not about groovy, it's about mocking a jdbc driver : it's not easy, and not really useful for a test

Comment: It seems that the array we are creating, we are doing it incorrectly.

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: EMAIL for class: java.util.ArrayList$Itr

Comment: you have now to mock a ResultSet. you should really look at the various in memory db. you can create a connection with 2 lines of code

Comment: mock the resultset .next() method within the sample code you provided?

Comment: the closure should be called with a Result. you have to configure and provide a mocked ResultSet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103027/discussion-between-angryip-and-jeremie-b).